# Serve a script to desktops only, not smartphones?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, colorbox, smartphone

I have YouTube videos in my site opening in a modal window (ColorBox).  When I try it on my iPhone, the window launches but the video doesn't play.

How can I prevent the modal window script from being served to smartphones, so that videos launch normally on those devices?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could sniff the [user agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent_string#User_agent_identification) with some javascript or even server side code, but make sure to give your users a way to switch manually between the two.

Nothing sucks more than getting the phone version on a computer because you're using an unknown browser like konqueror or getting the computer version on a phone because you're using a windows 7 phone.